# Pass a List to a params parameter

Tags: c#

Is there was a way to pass a `List` as an argument to a `params` parameter? Suppose I have a method like this:

```
void Foo(params int[] numbers)
{
    // ...
}
```

This way I can call it by passing either an array of `int`s or `int`s separated by commas:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 5, 3 };
Foo(numbers);
Foo(1, 5, 3);
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to also be able to pass a `List` as an argument (without having to convert it to an array). For example:

```
List<int> numbersList = new List<int>(numbers);
// This won't compile:
Foo(numbersList);
```

Comment: Related : [`params IEnumerable` language feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/179)

Answer (score 18):

## No

Sadly, that's the answer. No, there is not. Not without converting it to an array (for example with `.ToArray()`).

Answer (score 5):

You would want to change `Foo` to accept something other than `params int[]` to do this.

```
void Foo(IEnumerable<int> numbers) {
}
```

This would allow you to pass in either an `int[]` or a `List<int>`

To allow both ways, you could do this:

```
void Foo(params int[] numbers) {
   Foo((IEnumerable<int>)numbers);
}
void Foo(IEnumerable<int> numbers) {
   //Do the real thing here
}
```

Comment: But it does not have compiler support to call it like "Foo(1,2,3);".

Comment: No.  You would have to call it Foo(new int[] { 1,2,3 }).  I would do two overloads if you needed that

Comment: I added an example with the overloads that will allow you to call it either way

Comment: Yes, I had thought of that. I was looking for a way to have the 3 possibilities. But as it is not possible, which of the two options would be a better practice or a more flexible way to do it? Or should I just overload the method?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't refreshed the browser and didn't read some answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If able to change the existing code, you could always create an overload that accepts a List and passes it to the params method.

```
void Foo(params int[] numbers)
{
    // ...
}

void Foo(IList<int> numbers) => Foo(numbers.ToArray());
```

Comment: Is there any difference/advantage between using IList instead of IEnumerable?

Comment: @serious6 `IList` is derived from `IEnumerable` via `ICollection` so by using `IEnumerable` you give yourself more flexibility (you can cast to `IList` if you need a list, or just use the `IEnumerable` as it is)

Comment: Your question was about passing a List so I didn't want to assume the contract you wanted passed that. Using IEnumerable would indeed be more flexible. I don't think there would be compiler ambiguity between IEnumerable and int[] if you pass in params. I would work toward a solution that uses the least amount of method calls. If most calls would be from Lists, then I'd make the List/IEnumerable method the main method and have the params pass through. Otherwise leave it as it is above.